# Pls help to create a function on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

function dataframe that takes a
dictionary as input and creates a dataframe
from the dictionary, Sort the dictionary.

Instructions

```
1. Create a dataframe with the input dictionary
2. Columns should be Name Age
3. Print "Before Sorting"
4. Print a Newline
5. Print the dataframe before sorting. 
Note: Printing the dataframe must not contain index.
6. Print a Newline
7. Sort the dataframe in ascending order based on Age column
8. Print "After Sorting"
9. Print a Newline
10. Print the dataframe after sorting. Note: Printing the dataframe must not contain index.
```

▾ Sample Case 0

Sample Input

['william':42, 'George' :10, 'Joseph
:22, 'Henry':15, 'Samuel':32, 'David':18]

Sample Output

Before Sorting

Name    Age

William  42

George. 10

Joseph. 22

Henry.  15

Samuel. 32

David.  18

After Sorting

Name.  Age

George. 10

Henry.  15

David.  18

Joseph. 22

Samuel. 32

William. 42

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
def dict_to_df(key, value):
    my_dict = {key:value,key:value,key:value,...}
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()),columns = ['column1','column2'])
    print("Before Sorting"/n)
    print df.to_string(index=False)
    df.sort_values(by=['col2']
    print("After Sorting"/n)
    print df.to_string(index=False)'
```